# How can I activate info: links in Konqueror

Tags: info, konqueror

man: and help: work fine, but if I enter an info: link it says:

> The requested operation could not be completed Cannot Initiate the
>   info Protocol Technical Reason: Unable to Launch Process
>
> Possible Causes:
>
> The program which provides compatibility with this protocol may not
>   have  been  updated with your last update of KDE. This can cause the
>   program to be incompatible with the current version and thus not
>   start. You may have encountered a bug in the program.

I do not know if this is a bug or if something has gone wrong with my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug (see: https://bugs.kde.org/359015). It appears to have been fixed upstream, but not in Ubuntu (at least not in 16.04).

The fix (present in the above bug report) consists of changing two lines in a perl script (`/usr/share/kde4/apps/kio_info/kde-info2html`), so it can be easily applied manually. In patch format:

```
@@ -171,7 +171,7 @@
        next if $looking && !/\* Menu/;
        $looking = 0;
        my @item = &ParseMenuItem($_,'dir');
-       if (!defined(@item)) { next }
+       if (!@item) { next }
            my ($MenuLinkTag, $MenuLinkFile, $MenuLinkRef, $MenuLinkText) = @item;
        if ($MenuLinkRef eq $FileName) {
            &Redirect($MenuLinkFile, $MenuLinkTag);
@@ -429,7 +429,7 @@
 sub MenuItem2HTML {
     my ($Line, $BaseInfoFile) = @_;
     my @parse_results = &ParseMenuItem($Line, $BaseInfoFile);
-    if (!defined (@parse_results)) { return $Line; }
+    if (!@parse_results) { return $Line; }
     my ($MenuLinkTag, $MenuLinkFile, $MenuLinkRef, $MenuLinkText) = @parse_results;
     #-- produce a HTML line
     return "<tr class=\"infomenutr\"><td class=\"infomenutd\" style=\"width:30%\"><ul><li><a href=\"info:/$MenuLinkFile/$MenuLinkTag\">$MenuLinkRef</a></ul></td><td class=\"infomenutd\">$MenuLinkText";
```

Comment: Launchpad bug reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-runtime/+bug/1613851